# Scale multiple objects in place

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, scale, origin

I am trying to scale many objects that are in a circular formation around (0,0,0) but have them STAY in their respective coordinates. When I scale or transform all of the objects now, it changes the distance away from center.
In photoshop there's something like Object --> Transform Each. 
Is there something similar in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is just to change the *Pivot Center* to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

Now when you scale up your objects they stay in their position:

[image]

Comment: yes precisely! thanks!